# Can Exchange server 2010 drop mail destined to an internal address into a drop folder?

Tags: exchange-2010

If my domain is @contoso.com and I want emails destined to service@contoso.com to end up in a UNC share on the network. Can a foreign connector be setup for a specific address on the local  domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using Exchange 2010 alone, but you could *forward* those e-mails to *another server* (linux based?) which is probably able to do that.

One other way would be a *powershell* script, which exports the *service@contoso.com* mailbox periodically to an *UNC share*, but this only gets you a *.PST* file, and not a *.MSG* or whatever format you need.